# Are side effects always visible in task continuations?

Tags: .net, task, side-effects

Are side effects guaranteed to be visible in task continuations?

```
object o = null;
Task.Run (() => o = new object ())
    .ContinueWith (t => o.ToString ());
```

The continuation may run on a different thread than the first task. If there is no kind of memory fence, the assignment to `o` might not be visible to the continuation. In that case, a NullReferenceException would be thrown. Is there anything that already prevents this in the above example?

Comment: I don't think there's anything formally documented but continuations would be fairly useless if you weren't guaranteed to see the effects of the task.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I guess continuations would usually use the task result directly, so they don't suffer from this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are side effects guaranteed to be visible in task continuations?

If that's "is there some official documentation from MS somewhere that says so" then I'm afraid the answer is no.

As a practical matter, continuations would not be useful if they couldn't rely on being able to observe all effects produced by the task they're continuing from<sup>1</sup>.

Both the [.NET Framework 4.8 source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs,3589) and the [core clr](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/4f9ae42d861fcb4be2fcd5d3d55d5f227d30e723/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/Task.cs#L3203) have an internal method called `FinishContinuations` that is used to find the continuations a `Task` object has and cause them to be scheduled/executed. In both implementations, an `Interlocked.Exchange` is used to obtain the continuation object and hopefully you're already aware that that imposes a full memory barrier.

---

I've also found this [Blog Post](https://afana.me/archive/2015/07/10/memory-barriers-in-dot-net.aspx/) (not from MS) that contains a list of items that force memory barriers. Task completions are on the list but there aren't any references to more authoritative sources.

I also checked the [BotR](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/Documentation/botr/README.md) but couldn't find any statements on this specifically.

---

<sup>1</sup>Bearing in mind that we can have `Task.ContinueWith`, not just `Task<T>.ContinueWith` - i.e. it supports scenarios where nothing is being directly delivered from the task to the continuation.